# Tracking individual requests to Open Graph through iOS SDK

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api, delegates

I'm building an app, essentially a very basic Facebook client using the Facebook SDK for iOS. I have implemented the `FBRequestDelegate` protocol, and am sending my requests to the Open Graph API in the following way

`[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self]`

This works fine, and once the requested content arrives, the SDK calls the delegate method,  passing in the data

`- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result`

My question is, does anyone know the best practice way to use the `FBRequest` passed into the delegate method to explicitly identify it as coming from my original request?

If I make several requests, how can I differentiate which request the delegate call is related to? I'm using `BOOL` flags, and only doing one request at a time at the moment, but it's not a good way of doing it.

Any help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `requestWithGraphPath` returns a `FBRequest` object which will be also passed to `request:didLoad` later. So you can simply compare the two objects and determine if they're the same.